# How can I send notifications to users who are offline in vuejs using `Notification` object?

Tags: node.js, vue.js, socket.io, notifications, adminlte

I want make a Notification sender for my website I use Notification Object and socket.io.I create a Page to write title and body of notification .
notification is working and send notification to user that online in website.
but I want sent to offline user too.

I make this site useing vuejs and nodejs in back-end.

This is my socket that send notification in to server :

```
      export default{
           data(){
                  return{
                 title:"",
                 text:"",
                   socket: io("http://localhost:2000"),
                 }
             };
           methods:{
          sendNotification(){

           this.socket.emit("sendingNotification",{title:this.title,text:this.text});

          }
     };
 }
```

I get `title` and `text` of this form :

````
     ```
       <div class="content-wrapper" style="min-height: 915.8px;">
       <section class="content">
             <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6">
          <div class="box box-info">
        <div class="box-header with-border">
          <h3 class="box-title">ارسال نوتیفیکیشن  </h3>
        </div>
        <!-- /.box-header -->
        <!-- form start -->
        <form class="form-horizontal">
          <div class="box-body">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">سرتیتر</label>

              <div class="col-sm-10">
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputEmail3"   placeholder="سرتیتر" v-model="title">
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="inputPassword3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">متن</label>

               <div class="col-sm-10">
                 <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputPassword3" placeholder="متن " v-model="text">
               </div>
             </div>

           </div>
           <!-- /.box-body -->
           <div class="box-footer">
             <button type="submit" @click.prevent="sendNotification" class="btn btn-info pull-right">ارسال</button>
           </div>
           <!-- /.box-footer -->
         </form>
       </div>
       </div>
      </div>
    </section>
  </div>

      ```
````

this is my socket.io code in Nodejs :

```
           let express = require('express');
           let app=express();
           let http = require('http').createServer(app);
           let io = require('socket.io')(http);

           io.on('connection', socket => {
             socket.on("sendingNotification",(bodyMessage)=>{
            console.log(bodyMessage);
            io.emit("sendNotification",bodyMessage);
            });
          });
         http.listen(2000);
```

and I get above event in to vuejs file  And send Notification:

```
       socket.on("sendNotification", body => {

          const not=new Notification(body.title,{
                 body:body.text,

            });

          });
```

anyone can help show notifications sent offline to users after they are online

Comment: You have to save the message in db(or somewhere in server-side) and push once user logins again.

Comment: socketio cannot send offline(while users are not logged in) notifications, you might need to use native Notification API. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/notification which is quite complex as far as i know =(